# Are there naming conventions for pip requirements files?

Tags: python, pip, naming-conventions, requirements.txt

Are there conventions for storing multiple `requirements.txt` files in a Python code repository. For example, one file for simply running the program, another for day-to-day development, another for making a Windows build.

- Some repositories contain two files, `requirements.txt` and `requirements_dev.txt`, or `requirements.txt` and `requirements_win.txt` - this seems pretty ad-hoc.
- I have others with a `requires` subfolder. But I'm not sure what the meaning of `requires/requirements.txt` is in this context -- running the application, or for development?
- There is no mention of storing multiple requirements files in [Structuring your project](https://python-guide-pt-br.readthedocs.io/en/latest/writing/structure/) (Hitchhiker's guide to Python) or [pip install](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/) (pip documentation).

Comment: Often, you'll see `requirements_dev.txt` for development.

Comment: Good question, I'm also curious if there are any conventions or at least best practices for this.

Comment: @AryaMcCarthy thanks I've added that as an example

Comment: also posted https://github.com/kennethreitz/python-guide/issues/821

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I am aware, there are no hard-and-fast rules here.  At least not via PEP (but someone feel free to correct me).

[The Hitchhiker's Guide to Python](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/structure/) recommends putting the `pip` requirements file at the root of your project.

There does not appear to be any requirement that a `pip` requirements file has to be called `requirements.txt`.  The [pip install documentation](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/reference/pip_install/#requirements-file-format) even uses the example of `pip install -r example-requirements.txt`.

I would think that the conventions vary from project-to-project and largely depend on your deployment process and project-specific documentation.